# grep in a directory and return just 1 result for each file in Unix Shell scripting

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, scripting, grep

I'm trying to grep into a directory which has a couple of files, I'm trying to grep by IP address, my problem is, in a single file the ip address is repeated at least 3 or 4 times, and I just want to get 1 result and continue with the grep in the other file

This is what I'm trying to do and I don't have any luck with it.

```
grep 10.01.10.0 log/MY_DIRECTORY_FILES* | sort -t . -k 2 | head -1
```

This is just returning 1 result.

Comment: Do you need the actual match? Or would a count of matches in the file do too?

Comment: I will get the count of matches, but first I'm just making sure that I'm not getting matches from the same file.

Comment: The point was whether the count of matches is what you actually want or whether you actually want the contents. Because that can change things.

Comment: I want the count, but I don't want the count for 3 or 4 matches of 1 file, I just want 1 match for the 1 file and then continue with the next file, for each one, the count will be 1 in case it match with the pattern that I'm trying to find for each file.

Comment: You just want the count of files that have the match? Then why sort? Does `grep -l 10.01.10.0 log/MY_DIRECTORY_FILES* | wc -l` get you what you want?

Comment: Awesome! It works!

I'm sorting due I'm getting by date, that's the reason why I was sorting

Thank you! -l option works for me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

`head -1` returns the first line of the entire input it sees. You have it at the end of your sorted pipeline.

So `grep` spits out every matching line from every file. `sort` then sorts *all* the lines and outputs them. `head` then returns the very first line it sees.

That's not what you want. You want `grep` to stop after the first match in each file. Fortunately, that's what the `-m` option to `grep` does.

> -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
>
> ```
> Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.  If the  input  is
> standard  input  from a regular file, and NUM matching lines are
> output, grep ensures that the standard input  is  positioned  to
> just  after the last matching line before exiting, regardless of
> the presence of trailing context lines.  This enables a  calling
> process  to resume a search.  When grep stops after NUM matching
> lines, it outputs any trailing context lines.  When  the  -c  or
> --count  option  is  also  used,  grep  does  not output a count
> greater than NUM.  When the -v or --invert-match option is  also
> used, grep stops after outputting NUM non-matching lines.
> ```

So you want to use:

```
grep -m 1 10.01.10.0 log/MY_DIRECTORY_FILES* | sort -t . -k 2
```

If your version of `grep` (OpenBSD? Solaris?) doesn't have the `-m` option (and doesn't have any other equivalent option) then you have to run `grep` multiple times.

```
for file in log/MY_DIRECTORY_FILES*; do
    grep 10.01.10.0 "$file" | head -n 1
done | sort -t . -k 2
```

You could also, to avoid running `grep` N times, use something like this (with `gawk`):

```
awk '/10.01.10.0/ {print; nextfile}' log/MY_DIRECTORY_FILES*
```

For non-`gawk` you would need something more like this (untested):

```
awk '!f && /10.01.10.0/ {print; f=1; next} oARGIND != ARGIND {f=0; oARGIND=ARGIND}' log/MY_DIRECTORY_FILES*
```

Comment: unfortunately I tried that option but I get an error, I just have these options with grep
-b, -c, -h, -i, -l, -n, -s, -v, w

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Etan Reisen
This was his solution and it works for me!

grep -l 10.01.10.0 log/MY_DIRECTORY_FILES* | wc -l

I verified using grep -l 10.01.10.0 log/MY_DIRECTORY_FILES* and is only showing 1 result.

Thanks